# forward declaration of procedure in delphi

Tags: delphi, procedure, forward-declaration

How can I make a forward declaration of a procedure in Delphi and make it's implementation in other place? I want to do something like this C's code but in Delphi:

```
void FooBar();

void FooBar()
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you look up forward declaration in the documentation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Most likely because if he knew what to look for, he wouldn't have to look it up.  Looks like his experience is with C, which doesn't have a `forward` keyword or anything like it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Read the subject of the question again. Type that into the Delphi doc search. This is what happens: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Search/?cx=0017879905796164350846%3Ad3x3zsyivu0&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&lr=lang_en&q=forward+declaration+of+procedure+in+delphi&sa=Go&siteurl=docwiki.embarcadero.com%2FRADStudio%2FXE4%2Fen%2FMain_Page&ref=docs.embarcadero.com%2Fproducts%2Frad_studio%2F&ss=160j25600j2  We should be encouraging people to use the documentation. Your answer should include a reference to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I just haven't searched for delphi's documentation source. My bad.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You do that with the `forward` directive, like so:

```
procedure FooBar(); forward;

...
//later on

procedure FooBar()
begin
    // Do something
end;
```

This is only necessary if you're declaring it as an internal function. (ie. already inside the `implementation` section of your unit.)  Anything declared as a method of a class, or in the `interface` section of the unit, is automatically understood to be forward-declared.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way of doing it, through the interface/implementation part of a unit.

```
Unit YourUnit;

Interface

  procedure FooBar();  // procedure declaration


Implementation

// Here you can reference the procedure FooBar()

procedure FooBar();
begin
  // Implement your procedure here
end;
```

You should also take a look into the documentation about [`forward declarations`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Forward_and_Interface_Declarations), where another option is mentioned, like @MasonWheeler answered.